# how to ignore blank lines and comment lines using awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

i am writing this code:

```
awk -F'=' '!/^$/{arr[$1]=$2}END{for (x in arr) {print x"="arr[x]}}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

this code ignore blank lines, but i also want to ignore line starting with # (comments).

Any idea how to add multiple patterns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `!/^$/` to

```
!/^($|#)/
```

or

```
!/^($|[:space:]*#)/
```

if you want to disregard whitespace before the `#`.

Comment: This should not work!  The `(` do not need to be escaped in awk EREs, so this should be suppressing lines that begin with the literal string `($|#)`.  In what version of awk is this actually working?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I mistakenly edited it to have the escapes just as OP was testing it.  I've edited it back to the correct, original version.

Answer (score 10):

```
awk 'NF && $1!~/^#/' data.txt
```

Will print all non-blank lines (number of fields `NF` is not
zero) and lines that  don't contain `#` as the first field.

It will handle a line of whitespace correctly since NF will be zero, and leading blanks since `$1` will ignore them.

Comment: This wouldn't ignore a line that has only whitespace.

Comment: @vergenzt I don't think your comment applies any longer - if it does please let me know, thanks.

Comment: It detects whitespace-only lines correctly now, but this test case fails: `echo "This# is not a comment" | awk 'NF && $1!~/#/'` :/

Comment: @vergenzt Wow .. good catch .. thanks. This is easily fixed with `^#` .. `echo "This# is not a comment" | awk 'NF && $1!~/^#/'`. I'll test some more other cases. Feedback much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NF && !/^[:space:]*#/' data.txt
```

Because '[:space:]*' catches *none* or more spaces.